# Collabion Charts and unintended styling (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: css, sharepoint, fusioncharts

I'm working for a client and just had to fix an issue caused by Collabion Charts (I think made by FusionCharts).  Collabion's ext-all.css file has some very generic selectors using tag names, grabbing/filtering base html elements.  Obviously this will style all elements on the page, not just the elements associated with the Collabion content.  If you dig into any of the chart's HTML you see that there is a container div with ID "chartPanelContainer".  My solution was to modify the css file so that it would filter only the elements mentioned above contained within ID "chartPanelContainer".

Example:
`td {
    margin:0;
}`

Becomes:
`#chartPanelContainer td {
    margin:0;
}`

In my environment the css file could be found here:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\CollabionCharts\ext\resources\css\ext-all.css

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I answered my own question.. just couldn't literally answer it due to being a new user / low reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using very very old version because this has been fixed long time ago.

Comment: I may be - I'm a consultant and have no control over any of that.

Comment: I forgot to come back to this.. you sir, were correct.  Their version was extremely out of date by the time it was finally made current.